# Data collection process in survival analysis

Tags: survival

I must apologize if this seems a very basic question. I am fairly new to survival analysis. Could some please enlighten me on how survival data is collected? I am very much aware of some of the techniques used to analyze survival data.

**Added after comment**

For instance, suppose I want to model the data using a piecewise exponential model, how would I go about collecting the data?

Comment: I think you'll get better answers by asking a more narrow question. As it stands, the question is very broad.

Comment: @ swmo I don't know exactly what you mean but hopefully my edit suffices.

Comment: You can see following links for how the data is arranged: http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/examples/asa/asa_ch2_r.htm  and http://www.mas.ncl.ac.uk/~nmf16/teaching/mas3311/practical1.html

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally, you should collect data in a way that justifies the assumptions of your desired model of the process / allows you to answer questions of your population of interest.  For example, data that justifies assumptions of iid, is representative of the population, etc.

Note that survival analysis can deal with censored data, you do not need to exclude observations for which the event(s) of interest have not yet occurred.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have data on how much time has elapsed since treatment application, last activity, or days as a customer before churn, for example. You also need to know if the event under consideration has occurred yet or not (churn, death, cancelled subscription). If you are comparing two groups of subjects, you also need a variable which identifies the groups and can be used to plot different Kaplan-Meier survival curves.

For a churn setting example, I would have days as customer, churn status, and additional predictors such as demographic data and product type.

Answer (score 0):

For a basic Survival-analysis (no time-dependent covariates, no competing risks), you only need

- baseline covariates
- follow up time (either event-time if the event did happen or time to loss to follow up or dropout )
- Event-indicator: did the event of interest occur yes/no

The baseline-hazard/baseline survival describes the event-rates over time. That could e.g. be very low in the first year and higher afterwards, which may be modeled reasonably well with a piecewise exponential. Notice that this concerns the outcome (which you know/collected over time) and doesn't need intermediate measurements of covariates: your analysis is condional on *baseline*-covariates.